# Mapping web page or app that plots a route for n number of miles

Tags: maps

Is there a mapping web page or app that plots a route for n number of miles or km?

For example, I want to bike exactly 50 miles from a given location or to a given location.

Comment: I mean, the way we'd traditionally do it would be to draw a radius around a point on a paper map to indicate the outer limits, and then plot a desired route within that limit to the desired distance. An app would be challenging if you want to include things like bike trails and non public roads, and probably highly geographically limited.

Comment: Is this as the crow flies, or via roads?